# Windows browser specific to program within WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdg-open

I'm in a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

My `~/.zshrc` file currently has the following appended to the end of the file.

```
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe
```

When I try to run

```
xdg-open .
```

It fails to open the current working directory because the current browser is not compatible.

When running `xdg-open .`, I expect as if my `~/.zshrc` uses:

```
export BROWSER="powershell.exe /C start"
```

But only in the case where `xdg-open` is used. I would like to use **brave.exe** for all other cases as my default browser.

What is the best way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xdg-open` is typically for X applications.  As far as I know, there's not going to be a way to get it to understand and launch a Windows executable such as Brave.

Many WSL distributions, including Ubuntu 20.04 when installed from the Store, include the `wslview` command as an alternative for opening the default *Windows* applications.  For others who may be on different distributions, if it isn't available by default, it can be installed as part of the [wslu package](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu).

`wslview .` will open the directory in whatever application Windows would normal use for directory browsing.  This would typically be `explorer.exe`, but in my case I use Directory Opus instead.

I'm not sure how exactly you would override the default directory browser for Windows, though.  If Brave isn't set up to do this when you run `start .` from PowerShell or CMD, I don't think it's going to work for `wslview` either.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1031250/replace-windows-explorer-as-default-file-viewer-in-windows-10) for more details on that aspect.

If all else fails, you should always be able to create an alias (or better, shell function) that calls Brave on a path.